# Use angular element in old angular version (version 5,4..)

Tags: angular, element

I created an angular element by this guide:

https://www.google.com/amp/s/scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-reusable-component-with-angular-elements/amp

and I tried to put in basic html file and it worked fine.
But when I tried to use it in older angular version I got error like:
“Uncaught TypeError: parentJsonpFunction is not a function
at webpackJsonpCallback (bootstrap f3a05b3098d404d7f157:18)
at polyfills.bundle.js:1”

My question is : is it possible to do what I tried to do?

Comment: Sharing some code may help to get a useful answer. You may want to read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) how to write a good question.